# How to show current date and time list in dropdown in magento2.1.7?

Tags: magento2, timezone, datetime

How to show current date and time list in dropdown in magento2.1.7, As I have purchased an extension for store pickup in my magento2 site..
But the date , time functionality is not working properly, so I am trying to create a new controller for getting date and time.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject in your class constructor an instance of `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime` and use that one.
Something like this:

```
protected $date;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->date = $date;
    ....
}
```

Then, you can use in your class this:

```
$date = $this->date->gmtDate();
```

Comment: I have tried this, it is not working..